# Dataframes based off the value in the last row

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I subset a CSV in R based on the value in each column of the last row?

For example, I read in a CSV file called mnist.csv and it is of dimension 400x600.

```
columns   1 2 3 4 .......... 600
rows:   1
        2
        3
        4
        .
        .
        .
      400 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...3 3 3
```

I want to create dataframes that will only have the column and rows where the value is `0` in the last row and another dataframe where the value is `1` in the last row

Comment: Similar to `mtcars[,mtcars[nrow(mtcars),] == 4L,drop=FALSE]`? (using 4 instead of 0)

Comment: Show us what you have tried and also what the output should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sample data, looking instead for `4` instead of `0`:

```
mtcars[,mtcars[nrow(mtcars),] == 4L,drop=FALSE]
```

Disecting that:

- `nrow(mtcars)` allows us to index on the "last" of each column
- `mtcars[...,]` returns a 1-D matrix, the last values of each column
- `... == 4L` returns a `logical` vector, corresponding to each column that matches
- `mtcars[,...,drop=FALSE]` just does the column-subsetting; the `drop=FALSE` is to guard against the matrix being simplified to a vector when only one column matches, as is the case in `mtcars[,mtcars[nrow(mtcars),] == 2L]`.